# How to aggregate last 12 months user count using kafka windows?

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

Hi I am recently started working of kafka streams java api. Can you please hlep on the below use case how we can solve in kafka streams.

We are looking for distinct users count who registered in last 12 months. For example if the current month is Aug 2022 then i need the count of users between 1st Aug 2021 to 31st July 2022.
I am trying with tumbling window with 365 days duration but its not suits for the requirement.  Is there any why we can define between interval aggregation in kafka streams.

uesr1 registered on 1st June 2021
user2 registered on 3rd June 2022

If we run the kakfa processor in 1st Aug 2022 and it should look for the records between (2021-08-01 to 2022-07-31) and expecting count is 1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is possible. One obstacle is that 12 month are most of the time 365 days, but in case of a leap year 366 days(not even considering leap seconds). So you can not use a window with a fixed time period.
Since you only want distinct users, you habe to compare a user from 2021-08-01 with a user from 2022-07-31. So you have to keep all registrations at one place.

My Question would be why not do it from the Database? I assume the registered users are already saved there(you also have to keep the deleted users for 12 month) and it would only one SQL query.
If you have to use Kafka Streams you might look into KSQL (https://www.confluent.io/de-de/blog/ksql-streaming-sql-for-apache-kafka/)